# PHP Pass Dynamic Array name to function

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

How do I pass an array key to a function to pull up the right key's data?

// The array

```
<?php

$var['TEST1'] = Array (
    'Description' => 'This is a Description',
    'Version' => '1.11',
    'fields' => Array(
            'ID' => array(
                    'type' => 'int',
                    'length' =>'11',
                    'misc' =>'auto_increment'
            ),
            'DATA' => array(
                    'type' => 'varchar', '
                    length' => '255'
            )
    );

$var['TEST2'] = Array (
            'Description' =? 'This is the 2nd Description',
            'Version' => '2.1',
            'fields' => Array(
                    'ID' => array(
                            'type' => 'int',
                            'length' =>'11',
                            'misc' =>'auto_increment'
                    ),
                    'DATA' => array(
                            'type' => 'varchar', '
                            length' => '255'
                    )
            )
```

// The function

```
<?php

$obj = 'TEST1';
print_r($schema[$obj]); // <-- Fives me output.  But calling the function doesn't.

echo buildStructure($obj);

/**
 * @TODO to add auto_inc support
 */

function buildStructure($obj)
{
    $output = '';
    $primaryKey = $schema["{$obj}"]['primary key'];

    foreach ($schema["{$obj}"]['fields'] as $name => $tag)
        // #### ERROR ####  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
    {
        $type = $tag['type'];
        $length = $tag['length'];
        $default = $tag['default'];
        $description = $tag['description'];

        $length = (isset($length)) ? "({$length})" : '';
        $default = ($default == NULL ) ? "NULL" : $default;

        $output .= "`{$name}` {$type}{$length} DEFAULT {$default} COMMENT `{$DESCRIPTION}`, ";


    }
    return $output;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is followed by incredible buggy code, but here is a fixed code, which return the result you need:

```
<!-- language: lang-php -->
<?php
// How do I pass an array key to a function to pull up the right key's data?
$var['TEST1'] = Array (
    'Description' => 'This is a Description',
    'Version' => '1.11',
    'Fields' => Array(
            'ID' => array(
                    'type' => 'int',
                    'length' =>'11',
                    'misc' =>'auto_increment'
            ),
            'DATA' => array(
                    'type' => 'varchar', 
                    'length' => '255'
            )
    )
);
$var['TEST2'] = Array (
            'Description' => 'This is the 2nd Description',
            'Version' => '2.1',
            'Fields' => Array(
                    'ID' => array(
                            'type' => 'int',
                            'length' => '11',
                            'misc' =>'auto_increment'
                    ),
                    'DATA' => array(
                            'type' => 'varchar', 
                            'length' => '255'
                    )
            )
);


function buildStructure($obj)
{
    global $var;
    $output = '';
    // $primaryKey = $VAR[$obj]['primary key']; // Primary key is not 
    // defined in original array!!!
    foreach ($var[$obj]['Fields'] as $name => $tag){
        $type = $tag['type'];
        $length = $tag['length'];
        $default = (array_key_exists('default', $tag)) ? $tag['default'] : '';
        $description = (array_key_exists('description', $tag)) ? $tag['description'] : '';
        $length = (isset($length)) ? "({$length})" : '';
        $default = ($default == NULL ) ? "NULL" : $default;
        $output .= "`{$name}` {$type}{$length} DEFAULT {$default} COMMENT `{$description}`, ";
    }
    return $output;
}

$obj = 'TEST1';
echo buildStructure($obj);
// output is: 
// `ID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT ``, `DATA` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT ``,
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks as though there's a few things wrong:

1. You are putting your arrays into `$var` but the function looks inside `$skema`
2. Your function access $skema but that variable hasn't been defined
3. The array key is `Fields` not `fields`

```
$obj = 'TEST1';
$skema = array(
    'TEST1' => array(
        'Description' => 'This is a Description',
        'Version' => '1.11',
        'Fields' => Array(
            'ID' => array(
                    'type' => 'int',
                    'length' =>'11',
                    'misc' =>'auto_increment'
            ),
            'DATA' => array(
                    'type' => 'varchar', '
                    length' => '255'
            )
        )
    )
);
echo buildStructure($obj);

/**
 * @TODO to add auto_inc support
 */

function buildStructure($obj, $skema)
{
    $output = '';
    $primaryKey = $skema[$obj]['primary key'];

    foreach ($skema[$obj]['Fields'] as $name => $tag)
    {
        $type = $tag['type'];
        $length = $tag['length'];
        $default = $tag['default'];
        $description = $tag['description'];

        $length = (isset($length)) ? "({$length})" : '';
        $default = ($default == NULL ) ? "NULL" : $default;

        $output .= "`{$name}` {$type}{$length} DEFAULT {$default} COMMENT `{$DESCRIPTION}`, ";


    }
    return $output;
}
```

Comment: sorry that was from typing it out on stackoverflow.  I'll edit appropriately but it doesn't seem to work even with these fixes.

Comment: Point 2. from my list still applies to your edit, $schema is defined outside of the function and is *not* global, therefore it cannot be accessed from inside the function. To make $schema available to the function you could pass it into the function as second parameter

Comment: Cool Your code works, THANK YOU!  I thought the $schema being declared outside of all functions/classes made it public is why I didn't pass it along.